# Android Contacts: how to get contact list with first name, last name and a picture

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

Is there a way to get all device contacts (aggregated, not raw) with contact ID, fist/last name, and contact picture?

Currently I am using the code below but it does not return structured name:

```
private static final String CONTACTS_SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

// all contacts
public final String[] columns = {
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,                                  
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};

c = contentResolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CONTACTS_SORT_ORDER);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to fetch the required data with one query. For each contact ID you'll have to query its Data directory:

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
Uri dataUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
```

Then you should run queries against this URI, filtering `MIMETYPE` by `StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` to obtain `StructuredName` for the given ID.

```
Uri dataUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
Cursor nameCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
        dataUri,
        null,
        Data.MIMETYPE+"=?",
        new String[]{ StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE },
        null);
```